# NSString copy not copying?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

```
  NSString *myString = @"sample string";
  NSString *newString = [myString copy];
```

If I set a breakpoint after these two lines, the pointer for myString is the same as the pointer for newString.

WTF?  Isn't NSString copy supposed to return a pointer to a new object?  Or am I missing something fundamental about how copy is supposed to work?

Comment: i don't know the answer but if you change myString then both have different address... until the content of the string is same it is in same address...

Comment: First, you didn't actually call copy, you called stringWithString:. Second, since strings are immutable, the compiler and runtime make optimizations. Usually immutable objects will be returned with an additional reference count rather than creating an actual new object.

Comment: Beauty of cocoa - not making copies of data when not required ...

Comment: Oops, sorry, that should have been a copy (tested a few different versions and pasted the wrong one).  Still, the behavior is the same.

Comment: @JasonCoco But it is an "optimization" of the framework, since `NSString` is a "ordinary" class, not a built-in type.

Answer (score 12):

Since `NSString` is **not mutable** it might just internally increase `ref count` and be done with it.

When you `release` one of those NSStrings it might just decrement `ref count` - standard memory management.

Do you see any issues with that?

Answer (score 8):

Think about this: `NSMutableString` is a subclass of `NSString`. When your property is declared as `NSString`, you don't expect it to change.

Consider, if you used `retain` and someone gave you an `NSMutableString` and then later on does change it, your class will be broken.

However, you may think that always `copy`ing is slow. So `NSString`'s `copy` simply calls `retain`. `NSMutableString`'s `copy` makes an actual copy.

It is usually better to give spit out an `NSString *` because people won't have to copy it all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can Allocate new variable like in sample

```
NSString *anotherString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:originalString];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a better practice to do copy the string value returned by a method, since the returned value maybe a mutable string object, and this value can be modified in other thread after returned by that method.