# How to retain my own objects and properties

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm not sure I understood how alloc and retain work.

Recently I discovered that the NSString properties were not retained and I had to add [myString copy] when I set them. Which makes me wonder if I misunderstood the whole way of using retain/alloc

Please, may someone tell me if I'm doing it correctly? I read a lot and had a look on open source projects, this let me thing that I may have been wrong since the beginning.

Here is my way of doing it:

```
/**** VIEW.h *****/
#import "MyClass.h"
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController  {
      //Is the following line really necessary?
    MyClass *myObject;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyClass *myObject;
- (void)defineObject;
@end
```

.

```
/**** VIEW.m *****/
#import "VIEW.h"
@implementation MyViewController
@dynamic myObject;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self defineObject];
    NSLog(@"My object's name is: %@", myObject.name);
}

- (void)defineObject
{
      //Here particularly, Why doesn't it work without both alloc and init
      //shouldn't "@property (nonatomic, retain) MyClass *myObject;" have done that already?
    myObject = [[MyClass alloc] initPersonalised];
    [myObject setName:@"my name"];
}
```

.

```
/**** MyClass.h *****/
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
      //not sure if this line is still necessary
    NSString *name;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;

- (id)initPersonalised;
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name;
- (NSString *)name;

@end
```

.

```
/**** MyClass.m *****/
#import "MyClass.h"
@implementation MyClass

@dynamic name;

(id)initPersonalised{   
    self = [super init];
    name = @"Undefined";
}
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name{
    self.name = [name copy];
}

- (NSString *)name{
    return [self.name copy];
}

@end
```

I hope you can bring a bit of light, after months of programming this way, I'm less and less sure of doing it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a topic that every Objective C programmer stumbles upon. There are a few things one needs to know:

**Instance variable vs. property access**

Within *MyViewController*,

```
myObject = xxx;
```

and

```
self.myObject = xxx;
```

are two different things. The first directly assigns to the instance variable and does neither release to old referenced insance nor retain the newly assigned instance. The latter one uses the property setter and thus releases the old and retains the new value.

**Deallocation**

Even when you have declared an implemented a property that takes care of retaining and releases the values, it won't take care of deallocation when your object (*MyViewController* in your case) is released. So you must explicitly release it in *dealloc*:

```
-(void) dealloc {
  [myObject release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

**Now to your code:**

The snippet:

```
myObject = [[MyClass alloc] initPersonalised];
```

is perfectly okay. When you create an object, you use the pair of *alloc* and *initXXX*. The always create an instance with the reference count set to 1. So by directly assigning it to the instance variable, you create a clean constellation. I don't see no other way of creating the instance.

In *MyClass* you could use `@synthesize name` instead of `@dynamic`. Then the compiler would implement `name` and `setName:` automatically and you wouldn't need to do it yourself.

Finally, your missing `dealloc`.

**Update:**

If you use:

```
self.myObject = [[MyClass alloc] initPersonalised];
```

then you have a memory leak because *initPesonalised* sets the reference count to 1 and the setter of myObject increases it to two. If you want to use the setter, then I has to be:

```
MyClass* mo = [[MyClass alloc] initPersonalised];
self.myObject = [[MyClass alloc] initPersonalised];
[mo release];
```

It would be different if you weren't using `initXXX` to create a new instance. The class NSString for example has many methods called `stringXXX`, which create a new instance (or return a shared one) that has (conceptually) a reference count of 1 that will later automatically decreased by one. Then you better use the setter:

```
self.name = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"instance %d", cnt];
```

If you want to use *copy* instead of *retain* for your string property (which is good practice), then you can simply declare your property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
```

When you then use `@synthesize` to implement the getter and setter, the compiler will generate them using *copy* instead of *retain*.

And `NSString *name;` is necessary even if you use `@property` and/or `@synthesize` to implement the property.

Comment: thank you, that helps me a lot, particularly the difference between `self.name` and `name` alone. 

So, instead of this, shouldn't I use `self.myobject = [[MyClass alloc] initPersonalised];`

@synthesize takes a `[NSObject copy]` for `setName`? or they keep sharing the same alloc?

True, I forgot dealloc in my example. But not in my code.

Would you know if the `NSString *name;` is necessary while I have after `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;` ?

Comment: After testing, it's clear I understood thanks to you, but NSString was a bad example, copy is ignored on a property with NSString. The only way to obtain a new Pointer is with `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",name]`  (cf [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521468/nsstring-copy-not-copying))

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). It will help you to better understand the alloc & retain concepts; hope this helps you.

Comment: The Cocoa Memory Management Guide should be a required prerequisite before posting any questions about this topic :)

Comment: @zoul and @Sarah nice and thank you for the link but some preliminaries are necessary to follow the new words created by Apple for their Objective C after 10 yrs of Java and C++... not that I didn't try, but this is a lot all together to digest.

I'm spending many hours every day in their documentation, let me some months to be at your level....

Answer (score 1):

Alloc and init are methods that always go hand-in-hand. `alloc` allocates space for your object, and init initializes your object to some value. When you call alloc, you are responsible for freeing that object later. If you call copy, you are also responsible for releasing that object later. It's considered good practice to always initialize your objects right after you allocate them.

Now, to answer the questions I found in your code.

```
   @interface MyViewController : UIViewController  {
      //Is the following line really necessary?
    MyClass *myObject;
}
```

So is that line necessary? That depends. Does it make sense that your object has a MyClass as a property? This is a question only you can answer based on your design. I recommend you to study Object-Oriented Programming in more depth.

```
- (void)defineObject
{
      //Here particularly, Why doesn't it work without both alloc and init
      //shouldn't "@property (nonatomic, retain) MyClass *myObject;" have done that already?
    myObject = [[MyClass alloc] initPersonalised];
    [myObject setName:@"my name"];
}
```

Not necessarily. You are just providing a pointer to an object of the specified kind. The moment you set your property, depending on the property modifiers, your class will know what to do with MyObject.

In that way, there's no need to call `[yourObject copy]`. In this way your properties will be copied instead of being retained. Just don't forget to release it later in your -dealloc method, like you would with retain properties.

All in all, this is what I recommend you to study a bit more:

- Object-Oriented Programming (not related to your issue, but I can tell you are not comfortable using it. Objective-C is heavily object oriented, so you want to understand OOP).
- iOS Memory Management.

Comment: thank you, this is because I'm comfortable in C++ and Java that I'm feeling lost in Objective-C, know knowing what is automatised or not. And I wondered if the line was really necessary because it works fine without it, just with the @property line