# Why does NSString copy returns the same string

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

```
po self.URL.copy
$1 = 0x1fc3ced0 http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&zoom=16&size=160x160&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true&center=-6.2032,106.7696&markers=size:small%7Ccolor:blue%7C-6.2032,106.7696
$2 = 0x1fc3ced0 http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&zoom=16&size=160x160&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true&center=-6.2032,106.7696&markers=size:small%7Ccolor:blue%7C-6.2032,106.7696
$3 = 0x1fc3ced0 http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&zoom=16&size=160x160&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true&center=-6.2032,106.7696&markers=size:small%7Ccolor:blue%7C-6.2032,106.7696
(lldb) po self.URL
$4 = 0x1fc3ced0 http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&zoom=16&size=160x160&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true&center=-6.2032,106.7696&markers=size:small%7Ccolor:blue%7C-6.2032,106.7696
```

I thought copy should return something the same but at a different address?

Answer (score 3):

`NSString` is immutable, so there's little reason to actually copy it. Instead it might simply increase the reference count internally. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521468/nsstring-copy-not-copying) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

If the string is immutable, then `copy` is effectively just a `retain`. Since the string's contents will never change, there is no need to duplicate the string's data.