# Objective C: which is faster alloc or copy

Tags: objective-c

I want to ask which is faster:

Making a new class object using `alloc+init` or making a `Copy` of the existing class object?

**edited**:

I was reading the prototype pattern and I got this query. In prototype pattern, we make a clone or copy of the existing object.
So in which case copy is faster than alloc?

Comment: The answer:  it depends on the class I suppose.  Do some profiling to find out.

Comment: From the implementations of `copyWithZone` that I've seen, they also call alloc/init, so I doubt there is much difference.

Comment: `copy` is faster than `alloc/init` when the implementation of `copy` is `return self;`.  That is the implementation for some of the immutable classes, e.g. `NSString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, of course, is **it depends** on what kind of object you're dealing with. For immutable objects such as NSString, calling `-copy` really only retains the original object. On the other hand, one can guess that copying an instance of NSMutableString involves both creating a new object and copying the data from the original object, and in such cases copying would obviously take longer than simply creating a new, empty object.

Comment: @Celeb, you mean to say incase of NSString, If we -copy the object then would it not create the different memory space for that object? Because in this case what will be the difference in retain and copy of immutable objects?

Comment: No difference. If you can't change the object once it's created, there's no need for more than one instance. See [NSString copy not copying?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2521468/643383) for an example. However, you don't always know that the NSString you have is immutable -- since NSMutableString is a subclass of NSString someone could pass a mutable string into a method, and copying a mutable string actually does create a new object. So use `-copy` when you mean to copy and don't worry about the fact that you *might* get back a pointer to the original object.